# WIX in Visual Studio proj setting to run WIX in separate processes?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

This may be wishful thinking on my part but I thought I had seen in the recent past (last 6 months or so) where in a Visual studio WIX project you can set a property in the project file to run the WIX processes such as Light, Candle etc in a separate process from the Visual Studio process.

I'm aware of the RunAsSeparateProcess attribute in the Heat task but I thought there was a more general project file setting for other WIX tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Doh...

Spent ages searching for the answer before I posted the question and then stumbled on the answer about 5 minutes after...

true

Comment: Would you mind sharing your answer instead of just saying you found it? You may help out other users by telling what you did.